# Ubuntu - Default Java, Oracle JDK not detected as installed

Tags: java, ubuntu, default

I have an ubuntu installation with Oracle JDK 1.8.0_141 was installed using the below guide.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps

tar was extracted to /opt/jdk and below commands used to set java as default.

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100

update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
```

java -version command works fine after these has been completed.

But when I try to install maven using apt-get it tries to install default-jre rather than using this installed version.

Any idea where can I change this default behavior.

Thanks

Comment: ask this on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Hi Gab, Thanks. Raised this on askubuntu.com

Comment: Did you set the variable JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: I have issues with setting, JAVA_HOME since it was previously changed by webupd8 oracle java ppa. I didn't tried it setting manually. I'll try setting JAVA_HOME and let you know the results on this. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Setting up JAVA_HOME didn't solved the issue. Since there were no deb file for java older version, does anyone know an easier way to which work with debian ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved after setting the kava alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/javaws" 1
```

It still install the default jdk when installing maven. But uses oracle jdk when building.

Thanks for the wikihow page : https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux